# NX Angular Jest: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'"

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest, narwhal

I have an internal NPM package I am importing for my NX Monorepo for work. While trying to run my unit tests I am getting errors pointing to that package whenever I have a 'spec.ts' file with an import from that NPM package. I have been looking around all over and I think I need to use the 'transformIgnorePatterns' in my 'jest.preset.js' file but it does not seem to be working.

Here is my jest.preset.js file:
`
const nxPreset = require('@nx/jest/preset').default;

```
module.exports = {
   ...nxPreset,

  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'html'],
  resolver: '@nx/jest/plugins/resolver',
  coverageReporters: ['html'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|mjs|js|html)$': ['jest-preset-angular', {
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
      astTransformers: [
        'jest-preset-angular/build/InlineFilesTransformer',
        'jest-preset-angular/build/StripStylesTransformer'
      ]
    }]
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*.mjs$|lodash-es)', '<rootDir>/node_modules/@a360'],
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment'
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts']
};
```

`

Here is my jest.config.ts file
`
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/naming-convention, @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const { getJestProjects } = require('@nx/jest');

```
module.exports = {
  projects: [
    ...getJestProjects(),
    '<rootDir>/libs/core/components/header',
    '<rootDir>/libs/core/components/table',
    '<rootDir>/libs/core/shared',
    '<rootDir>/apps/login/',
    '<rootDir>/apps/system-settings',
    '<rootDir>/apps/ui-showcase',
  ]
};
```

`

Here is my package.json

```
    {
      "name": "@aex/source",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "license": "MIT",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "nx": "nx",
        "affected": "nx affected",
        "affected:apps": "nx affected:apps",
        "affected:build": "nx affected:build",
        "affected:dep-graph": "nx affected:dep-graph",
        "affected:libs": "nx affected:libs",
        "affected:lint": "nx affected:lint",
        "affected:test": "nx affected -t test",
        "build": "nx build",
        "build:development": "nx run-many --target=build --all --configuration development --parallel=5",
        "build:production": "nx run-many --target=build --all --configuration production --parallel=5",
        "dep-graph": "nx dep-graph",
        "format": "nx format:write",
        "format:check": "nx format:check",
        "format:write": "nx format:write",
        "lint:all": "nx run-many --target=lint",
        "start": "nx serve",
        "test:all": "nx run-many --target=test",
        "test:login": "nx test login --configuration development",
        "test:ui-showcase": "nx test ui-showcase --configuration development",
        "test:system-settings": "nx test system-settings --configuration development",
        "update": "nx migrate latest",
        "workspace-schematic": "nx workspace-schematic",
        "start:all": "nx run-many --target=serve --configuration development --parallel=5 --proxy-config proxies/proxy-devbox.config.json",
        "start:ui-showcase": "nx serve ui-showcase --configuration development --proxy-config proxies/proxy-devbox.config.json",
        "start:system-settings": "nx serve system-settings --configuration development --proxy-config proxies/proxy-devbox.config.json",
        "start:login": "nx serve login --configuration development --proxy-config proxies/proxy-devbox.config.json",
        "prepare": "husky install"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@a360/ui": "^16.4.0-beta15",
        "@angular/animations": "~16.2.0",
        "@angular/common": "~16.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~16.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "~16.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~16.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~16.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~16.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "~16.2.0",
        "@nx/angular": "16.10.0",
        "ag-grid-angular": "^30.1.0",
        "ag-grid-community": "^30.1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "~16.0.0",
        "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
        "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
        "primeng": "^16.4.0",
        "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
        "tslib": "^2.3.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~16.2.0",
        "@angular-devkit/core": "~16.2.0",
        "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~16.2.0",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~16.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~16.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~16.0.0",
        "@angular/cli": "~16.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~16.2.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "~16.2.0",
        "@nx/eslint-plugin": "16.10.0",
        "@nx/jest": "16.10.0",
        "@nx/js": "16.10.0",
        "@nx/linter": "16.10.0",
        "@nx/playwright": "16.10.0",
        "@nx/web": "16.10.0",
        "@nx/workspace": "16.10.0",
        "@playwright/test": "^1.36.0",
        "@schematics/angular": "~16.2.0",
        "@swc-node/register": "~1.6.7",
        "@swc/core": "~1.3.85",
        "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
        "@types/node": "^16.11.7",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.60.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.60.1",
        "enhanced-resolve": "^5.15.0",
        "eslint": "~8.46.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-ban": "^1.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-diff": "^2.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "latest",
        "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^46.4.6",
        "eslint-plugin-playwright": "^0.15.3",
        "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^0.20.0",
        "husky": "^8.0.3",
        "jest": "^29.4.1",
        "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.4.1",
        "jest-preset-angular": "~13.1.0",
        "jsonc-eslint-parser": "^2.1.0",
        "lint-staged": "^15.0.1",
        "nx": "16.10.0",
        "prettier": "^2.6.2",
        "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
        "ts-node": "10.9.1",
        "typescript": "~5.1.3"
      },
      "lint-staged": {
        "**/*.{html,ts,scss,css}": [
          "prettier --write"
        ],
        "**/*.ts": [
          "npm run lint:all"
        ]
      },
      "husky": {
        "hooks": {
          "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
        }
      }
    }
```

I have tried the following in my 'transformIgnorePatterns'
transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*.mjs$|lodash-es)'],
transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*.mjs$|lodash-es)', 'node_modules/@a360'],
transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*.mjs$|lodash-es)', 'node_modules/@a360'],
transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*.mjs$|lodash-es/@a360)',
transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*.mjs$|lodash-es/@a360/*)'],

Comment: Jest should not be processing files in your node_modules directory so this directory should be ignored in any settings and not included.  For an easy look at what Jest needs to run the tests, simply create a new project in your NX workspace with Jest as the test engine, and look at the files created for that project. You can modify your Jest configuration after that, and then remove the project.